# Track ping, download and upload daily

Tags: networking

I'm with some problems with my internet with oscillations in connection, causing some sites to get "Not Found" page sometimes. This isn't all the time, just some random times daily.

My question is. There is any tool to monitor these basic information (ping, upload and download) daily to make an report and check the oscillations?

Because, if someone from internet provider come at my house, probably it won't see the oscillations.

Comment: Very good question, I had **exactly the same problem** few years ago and tried to write a simple application that would do this, though I failed. Looking forward to replies!

Comment: I will keep looking for answer and if got anything share here too :)

Comment: "Not found" errors are not local, but in the pages you are trying to visit, please, include the pages when this occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try many monitoring programs. For this particular purpose I've used Cacti in the past. I was graphing RTT to a few hosts and downstream/bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the issue, does it happen for a while?  If so, you could use an application called Wireshark.  You can install it from the software center.

It is a packet analyser and simply the best out there.  You can monitor your interface and get very detailed information about the traffic and what is happening.

I've used this for both personal and commercial fault resolution to high levels of success.  I find that issues like yours can stem from DNS issues seen on your ISP's servers.  This tool can show that sort of traffic and where the bottlenecks are.  It's also awesome to give a tech at an ISP one of these traces when you're confirming they have an issue that they won't admit to...